# How is the IsDefined method internally implemented in C# .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, attributes

As can be seen from the Microsoft reference source code:

```
    public virtual bool IsDefined(Type attributeType, bool inherit)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

All overloads for `IsDefined` boil down to this one.

So how is this method implemented internally or is it implemented by the compiler?

Comment: See github source code [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/3f041eb4856c97a04518d024e00161abbc3303f5/src/coreclr/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Reflection/RuntimeFieldInfo.cs#L74) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/85223ce6cb38fca0ff817be84fca3faf679f6373/src/coreclr/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Reflection/RuntimeCustomAttributeData.cs#L773)

Comment: @Charlieface Wish there was a way to accept a comment as the answer to the question

Comment: @Charlieface Also how did you search for the specific method by name like 'IsDefined' in the github repo?

Comment: There is a search button at the top, but I didn't do that, I just followed the source code. I didn't post an answer because I don't think this question is a good fit for [so]. It's far too broad: it's not clear how deep into the internals of the CLR and the reflection mechanism you want to go. I just linked them so you can follow the code yourself, there is also documentation on the repo to look at.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the .NET source code at https://referencesource.microsoft.com/

Seaching for Attribute.IsDefined reveals this main implementation for members

```
public static bool IsDefined(MemberInfo element, Type attributeType, bool inherit)
{
    // Returns true if a custom attribute subclass of attributeType class/interface with inheritance walk
    if (element == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("element");

    if (attributeType == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("attributeType");
        
    if (!attributeType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Attribute)) && attributeType != typeof(Attribute))
        throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Argument_MustHaveAttributeBaseClass"));
        Contract.EndContractBlock();

    switch(element.MemberType)
    {
        case MemberTypes.Property:  
            return InternalIsDefined((PropertyInfo)element, attributeType, inherit);

        case MemberTypes.Event: 
            return InternalIsDefined((EventInfo)element, attributeType, inherit);

        default:
            return element.IsDefined(attributeType, inherit);
   }

}
```

Comment: ReferenceSource is very old, and does not contain a lot of the internal code. See the github repo instead.